# Strange pattern in convolutional neural network performance

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, statistics, conv-neural-network

I am learning about VGG, and I was struck by the following performance graph:

[image]

My question is this: Looking at the graph, it seems that first there is rapid growth, which then gradually slows down. This makes sense to me, since it becomes more difficult to improve a model the smaller the loss is. However, there are also three sudden drops around the 50, 75, and 100 epoch mark. I am curious as to why **all the models** experience this drop and rebound at the same time? What is causing it?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common observation in complex model training.  For instance, classic CNNs exhibit this behaviour: AlexNet and GoogleNet have two drop-and-improve irruptions in their training patterns.  This is a very complex and organic effect of the model's holistic learning characteristics.

To oversimplify ... there are learning bottlenecks inherent in most models, even when the topology *appears* to be smooth.  The model learns for a while until the latter layers have adapted well during back-prop ... until that learning bumps into one of the bottlenecks, some interference in input drive and feedback that tends to stall further *real* progress in training the earlier layers.  This indicates a few false assumptions in the learning of those lower layers, assumptions which now encounter some statistical realities in the upper layers.

The natural operation of the training process forces some early-layer chaos back into the somewhat-stable late layers -- sort of an organic drop-out effect, although less random.  Some of "learned" kernels in the late layers prove to be incorrect, and get their weights re-scrambled.  As a result of this drop-out, the model gets briefly less accurate, but soon learns *better* than before, as seen in the graph.

I know of no way to predict when and how this will happen with a given topology.  My personal hope is that it turns out to be some sort of harmonic resonance inherent in the topology, something like audio resonance in a closed space, or the spots/stripes on many animals.

Comment: Thank you for this, it seems like an area that could be a topic of research!

Comment: I quite agree.  If you're headed there yourself, at least look up one set of physiology research.  Coat patterning in many animals (tiger stripes, leopard spots, etc.) results from the interactions of color-coding chemical signals that resonate over a surface model of the animal.  Once the researches understood the mechanism, they could model it with a sheet-metal cutout (like a tiger-skin rug) and vibrations from the physically critical points of the body.  Put granules on the sheet start the vibration, and you get the coat patterning in the lab.

Comment: Is this whole thing called bottleneck theory? I found some papers online that use more technical wording, so I just want to make sure that I am looking for the right thing :)

Comment: Bottleneck theory is usually an advanced, more focused technique, a method of utilizing the effect for forcing faster training.  You're in the right area, but likely beyond what you need to understand what's happening in your model.